# How to add Element to a List in Python inside another list

Tags: python, list, element

I'm trying to add `"7000"` element to this `list [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, ], 500], 30, 40]`

I want to add `7000` after `6000` on this `list` … already try some methods to add this element

Comment: Did you try `the_list[2][2].append(7000)`? What exactly are you having trouble with? Are you trying to find a general method to append to (or add the next item in the sequence) for the nested list that contains *thousands* or the one that contains *hundreds* or the one that contains *tens*? Regardless you need to show your attempt and explain how it is deficient. Please read [mre] and [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `append()` method to update an list in place

```py
>>> x = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]
>>> x[2][2].append(7000)
>>> x
[10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, 7000], 500], 30, 40]
```

You can use the `append()` method on any list, no matter how nested it is.

Answer (score 0):

your list:- `lst=[10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, ], 500], 30, 40]`

well see in your list at index position 2 there is another list

that list:-`[300, 400, [5000, 6000, ], 500]`

in the above list there is another list at index 2 i.e `[5000, 6000, ]`

so use `append()` method in this code:-

```
lst[2][2].append(7000)
```